# Javascript Fetch Exercise Question: Reading NewsApi Object

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Sorry if this overlaps another topic. It may be similar.

I am doing my first javascript exercise of pulling API data from NewsAPI and I am looking at the data.

```
{status: "ok", totalResults: 10, articles: Array(10)}
articles:Array(10)
 0:
   author: "OptimalBits"
   content: "With built in Cluster..."
   description: "A modern reverse proxy..."
   publishedAt: "2018-11-05T13:08:21.7344616Z"
   source: {id: "hacker-news", name: "Hacker News"}
   title: "OptimalBits/redbird"
```

I am trying to access the information inside this so I can generate a li of topics/descriptions.

What is it? Object? Object inside of Object (cue Xzibit meme)?

```
console.log(data.articles[0].title())
```

returns with

> undefined

Comment: does data.articles[0].title return anything (without parentheses)?

Comment: as said above remove the parentheses and it should work

Comment: Putting parentheses after a name is for calling it as a function.

Comment: My bad.... this works console.log(data.articles[0].title);